# Parse array-like string into an array of json objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a String in the following format:

```
[{"type":"relativeHumidity","unit":"%","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]},{"type":"temperature","unit":"C","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]}]
```

It resembles an array of two json objects. I need to retrieve these JSON objects.

I have tried to parse it using JSON.parse(str) but complaints about the "," that separates JSONs in this array-like structure.

I have tried doing str.split(",") but it splits by each comma, e.g.

```
  [0] [{"type":"relativeHumidity"

  [1] "unit":"%"
```

I have tried removing first and last brackets and reading it as an array:

```
var arr = [str.substr(1, value.length - 2)];

[ '{"type":"relativeHumidity","unit":"%","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]},{"type":"temperature","unit":"C","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]}' ]
```

but it creates an array of a single string.

Any help on how to read that string into an array of JSON objects will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: array[0], array[1] should give you the two json strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me (no JSON parse error) > `JSON.parse('[{"type":"relativeHumidity","unit":"%","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]},{"type":"temperature","unit":"C","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0,"period":"INSTANT","correction":false,"completenessRatios":[{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"SIX_MONTHS"},{"completenessRatio":0.0,"period":"THIRTY_DAYS"},{"completenessRatio":0.5789037386601943,"period":"FULL_HISTORY"}]}]');`

tried it in chrome console

Comment: Thank you! I was unnecessarily removing first and last bracket, of which I forgot to mention in the post. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify({ "type":"relativeHumidity","unit":"%","resolution":300,"accuracy":0.0;})
```